# I am trying to solve a wordsearch but i cant get the words in order

Tags: recover-private-key

What should i do if i have 34 words but i only use 24 and they need to be in the right order. I have 6 words guaranteed correct and in the right order so that takes away 6 but then i still have the rest to get in the right order. I am pretty sure too that this will take 30 million years so im hoping someone has a faster way.

Comment: It would take much longer than "months" even if there were pre-built tools available for your specific scenario. Probably centuries will not be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **im hoping someone has a faster way.**

There's no way to reduce the number of permutations of 18 words chosen from 28 (thare are around 84019054401376174080000 of them).

I believe there are tools that can automatically check word permutations for seed-phrases if you have sufficient other data. I would look at btcrecover and similar tools.

Even so, I suspect you may be better off trying to work out what system (of obfuscation?) was used to prepare the list of 34 words.

Comment: Yes i know there is know what to lower the permutations but i meant to say is thera a way to calculate them faster? I have already tried btc recover but it would take a month the do everything needed to get the right seed. And btc recover does not support more than 24 words in the seed.

Comment: Thank you. I will probably just give up